# Unique Name for each UserID constraint in "Check Constraint Expression" window

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I'm trying to my setting names be unique for each user id

```sql
Table: Settings
Cols: ID, Name, Value, UserID
Row1: 1, 'Database', 'shop',  1
Row2: 2, 'DBLogin' , 'admin', 1
Row3: 3, 'DBPass'  , 'hash',  1
Row4: 4, 'Database', 'lol',   2 --this is ok
Row5: 5, 'Database', 'shop',  3 --this is ok
Row6: 6, 'Database', 'lol',   3 --this shoud be rejected
```

In "Check Constraint Expression" window of MS SQL Server MS, table creation I've tried such example

```sql
Name NOT IN (SELECT Name WHERE UserID = 3)
```

But even this causes error "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed. Incorrect syntax near ')'" 
Is there a way to achieve my goal? 
BTW. Is there a MS's equivalent of Oracle's :NEW.field? This would be useful:

```sql
Name NOT IN (SELECT Name WHERE UserID = :NEW.UserID)
```

...but it's stil a subquery
The main goal is to create a Dictionary of settings for each user(C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a unique constraint on it.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_settings_userid_name ON Settings (UserID, Name);
```

Comment: But that will restrict 'theName' to be inserted only once in the table.
'theName' should be possible to be duplicated for different UserID

Comment: Then make the constraint cover both columns e.g. on (UserID, Name). See the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @DamianK. sorry didn't got that part. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using either a `CONSTRAINT` or `Unique Index` one of them should be enough.

CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE Settings 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQSettings UNIQUE(Name, [Value])
```

Unique Index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQSettings ON Settings(Name, [Value])
```